# ASP.NET Databinder if else conditional asp control

Tags: asp.net

I have a object with value true or false. If the value is false, I want to display a asp:Button control, else it displays nothing. Can this be accomplished?
I want something like this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FullyPaid").Equals(false) ? "<asp:Button Text=\"Pay Now\"/>" : ""%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did worked like same here is what I used to play with Visible property:

```
Visible='<%#(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("pricetype")) == 1) ? true : false%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it the other way around:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPayNow" runat="server" Text="Pay Now" Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "FullyPaid")%>'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, but you must be sure that FullyPaid must contain either true or false.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnPayNow" runat="server" Text="Pay Now" 
Visible='<%#Eval("FullyPaid")%>'/>
```